# How to perform code-coverage test for Wireshark Lua dissector?

Tags: lua, code-coverage, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I trying to check coverage for my Lua dissector.
I tried to use 'luacov' framework for testing by including luacov package from from my Lua dissector.

When I run Wireshark with my dissector included, it can generate the 'luacov.stats.out' file. But the file is empty!

Does anyone have any ideas for this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `tick = true` in `.luacov`?

https://github.com/keplerproject/luacov#instructions